# Nested array recursion - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, recursion

I have a nested array containing children on a dynamic amount of levels, i want to generate a conditional tree based on this array.

An example of the array:

```
[
 {
  condition: 'conditionA',
  children: [
    {
      condition: 'conditionA_1',
      children: [
        ...
      ]
    },
  ]
 },
 {
  condition: 'conditionB',
  children: [
    ...
  ]
 }
]
```

I would like to generate a string that hold following conditional statement

```
if (conditionA) {
  if (conditionA_1) {
    ...
  }
} else if (conditionB) {
  ...
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas how to handle this properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and an example of what you expect

Comment: You mean, you want to generate source code? Or do you want to interpret the data structure so that it should behave *like* that output?

Comment: Yeah i would like to generate source code, the example that i expect is the conditional statement below.

Comment: Do want indentation as well or could it be a one-liner? Also, what should be inside those `if`s? And most importantly why do you need this?

Comment: Indentation does not matter, the insides of the conditions don't really matter i think

Comment: And why do you need this?

Comment: Do you plan to use `eval` with the generated string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Without indentation:

Just `map` each node in the array to `if(condition) { ... }` (recursively), then join the resulting blocks with `" else "`:

```
function makeSource(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(node) {
    return "if (" + node.condition + ") { " + (node.children? makeSource(node.children): "") + " }";
  }).join(" else ");
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
function makeSource(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(node) {
    return "if (" + node.condition + ") { " + (node.children? makeSource(node.children): "") + " }";
  }).join(" else ");
}

var array = [ { condition: 'conditionA', children: [ { condition: 'conditionA_1'} ] }, { condition: 'conditionB' } ];

var source = makeSource(array);

console.log(source);
```

#### With indentation:

To achieve the indentation we'll need a variable that holds the depth of the current block. Just repeat the space character before every line in the resulting string depending on the `depth` variable. Increate `depth` at each recursive call:

```
function makeSource(arr, depth = 0) {
  return arr.map(function(node) {
    var str = " ".repeat(depth * 2) + "if (" + node.condition + ") {\n";
    if(node.children) {
      str += makeSource(node.children, depth + 1);
    } else {
      str += " ".repeat((depth + 1) * 2);                      // unecessary, it just indents the empty line to where the code should be
    }
    return str + "\n" + " ".repeat(depth * 2) + "}";
  }).join(" else ");
}
```

The `* 2` parts represent the indentation number. If you want to indent by 4 spaces instead, then replace them with `* 4`.

**Demo:**

```js
function makeSource(arr, depth = 0) {
  return arr.map(function(node) {
    var str = " ".repeat(depth * 2) + "if (" + node.condition + ") {\n";
    if(node.children) {
      str += makeSource(node.children, depth + 1);
    } else {
      str += " ".repeat((depth + 1) * 2);
    }
    return str + "\n" + " ".repeat(depth * 2) + "}";
  }).join(" else ");
}

var array = [ { condition: 'conditionA', children: [ { condition: 'conditionA_1'} ] }, { condition: 'conditionB' } ];

var source = makeSource(array);

console.log(source);
```

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
 {
  condition: 'conditionA',
  children: [
    {
      condition: 'conditionA_1',
      children: [
        
      ]
    },
  ]
 },
 {
  condition: 'conditionB',
  children: [
    
  ]
 }
]

const createSource = arr =>{
  let source = "";
  
  if(arr.length === 0){
    return source;
  }
  
  arr.forEach((value,index) =>{
  
    source+="if( "+value.condition+" ){";
    if(value.children){
       source+=createSource(value.children)
    }
    source+="}" + (index+1  < arr.length ? " else " : "");
  })
  
  return source;
}
console.log(createSource(input))
```